# Constructive fixed-point theorems where finite iteration yields the fixed point

Tags: metric-spaces, order-theory, computability, lattice-orders, fixed-point-theorems

I would like to show that $p$, a fixed point of some effective map $f : S\rightarrow S$, can be constructed effectively.  Ideally, I would like there to exist a finite $n$ such that $p = f^n(p_0)$, where $p_0$ is a point in the domain of $f$.

What fixed-point theorem yields such a statement?  What are the conditions that $f$ and ${\rm dom}\ f$ must satisfy for the theorem to hold?

I would find order-theoretic fixed-point theorems useful, but other kinds of fixed-point theorem are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Tarski's fixed point theorem will give you just what you're looking for if the function is order-preserving and its domain is a complete lattice.

Comment: Thank you.  Informally and generally speaking, Tarski's theorem yields a fixed point after an "infinite" number of applications of the function.  That's unsatisfactory for my purpose.

Comment: If the lattice in question is finite, a finite number of applications of the function will yield a fixed point.